# How can I play my video after it was recorded with the camera?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

Im making a video camera app and I want to be able to play the recorded video I took after pressing the stop button. How would I be able to do that? This is the code I have here:

```
func stopRecording() {

    print("stop the recording")
    guard let writer = assetWriter else { return }

    assetWriterVideoInput = nil
    assetWriterAudioInput = nil
    assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor = nil
    assetWriter = nil

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.delegate?.recorderWillStartWriting()
    }

    capture?.queue.async {
        writer.endSession(atSourceTime: self.currentVideoTime)
        writer.finishWriting {
            switch writer.status {
            case .failed:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.recorderDidFail(with: RecorderError.couldNotCompleteWritingVideo)
                    print("fail")
                }
            case .completed:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.recorderDidFinishWriting(outputURL: writer.outputURL)
                    print("completed video")


                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.delegate?.recorderDidFinishRecording()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the URL of the output video at `writer.outputURL`

To play the video, just create an `AVPlayer`…

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
```

then either create an `AVPlayerLayer` and add it to a view

```
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

or present an `AVPlayerViewController`

```
let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
controller.player = player
```

then

```
player.play()
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing